# Sort the jqGrid rownumbers Descending order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have added rownumbers: true in jqGrid. The table is showing the data in ascending order.How to sort the jqGrid rownumbers column only in desc order

Comment: try to provide your code

Answer (score 0):

The goal of `rownumbers: true` option is displaying *the index of the row*. It has **no relation to the data** displayed in the grid and thus if can't be sorted.

You can extend your data with one more field which you set to 1, 2, 3, ... It will be the index of the item in the input data. You will be able to sort the column in the case.